# How to hide "... started debugging this browser" section in Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just typed a chrome extensions. These extensions are followed by "chrome.debugger.attach" and wss messages.

But when doing this, a section like in the picture appears because it opens the debug mode. How can I hide this part?[alt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wl1nM.png)

Comment: Run chrome with `--silent-debugger-extension-api` command line switch.

Comment: Yes this solved my problem. Thank you so much.